# Power button does not work! MBP 2011

Tags: keyboard, hardware, power

Overnight, my **MBP would not power on with the power button**. The Battery was full and the LED on the charger was green. *SMC Reset* did not bring any results. 
So I opend up the Mac, disconnected and connected the battery from the logic board and connected the charger to MPB. MPB turned on automatically, but the power button still doesn't work. 
I had problems with Caps-Lock and a few keys, but after *cleaning the keyboard connector* they disappeared. 
Power Button still does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is recommended to contact Apple authorised service provider and get your MacBook Pro inspected by a technician.

Comment: Since you seem to have some technical ability, you could attempt to change out the top case which is where the button is located.  Depending on the model MBP it's attached to the [keyboard](https://amzn.to/2Gbe3kk) meaning you only would need to change that part and not the whole thing.